# TCL Console error in Vivado 2014.4 while simulating

Tags: tcl, vhdl, vivado

After synthesizing my code successfully, on simulation, I often encounter an error saying

> [USF-XSim-62] 'compile' step failed with error(s). Please check the Tcl console output or '' file for more information.

I don't know how to open Tcl console output, or anything related to TCL console. But I have observed, at times, if I shift my VHDL code from C drive to some other drive, (only sometimes) I get rid of the error.
But I still don't know why does this error occur and how to resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried a recent version of Vivado?

Comment: I have access to only Vivado 2014.4

Comment: You haven't specified the platform. See [AR# 62969](https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/62969.html). Also note the image in [Re: Vivado Simulator ERROR: [USF-XSim-62\]](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Simulation-and-Verification/Vivado-Simulator-ERROR-USF-XSim-62/m-p/564473#M12109). The 'more information' would be the preceding error messages.